# Masonry only show single column

Tags: jquery, css, grid, jquery-masonry

Using masonry for the first time, and I can't seem to get it working properly. Currently only displays as a single column. I'm more of a designer than a dev, so it's likely I'm missing something. Here is the source:

```
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div id="container">
    <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="img/masonry_001.jpg">
    </div>
         
    <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="img/masonry_002.jpg">
    </div>
         
    <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="img/masonry_003.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="img/masonry_004.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="img/masonry_001.jpg">
    </div>
         
    <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="img/masonry_002.jpg">
    </div>
         
    <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="img/masonry_003.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="img/masonry_004.jpg">
    </div>
     
</div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

        <script>
  $(function(){

    var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  itemSelector: 'masonryImage'
});
  });
</script>

    </body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.masonryImage { width: 25%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I played with the JSFiddle to do what I think it is you actually want it to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/88tYe/5/

I set the divs to have a percentage width, and let the images inside the div be 100% (you didn't really specify if you wanted a gutter, so I left it out)

The code is very simple:

```
var $container = $('#container');
// initialize
$container.masonry({
   itemSelector: '.masonryImage'
});
```

And the css

```
#container { width:1200px }
.masonryImage { width: 25%; }
.masonryImage img { width:100%; }
```

Comment: I voted for your solution because you gave me a good idea... for me masonry made also only one column instead of three and I also wanted the image sizes in percentage. I did everything like masonry explains in their website but they complicated the things too much. Based on their explication, you must give the image size with an extra sizer element. I just simply deleted the sizer and applied the 30% image size within the image css directly and it works perfectly... simple like your example !

Answer (score 0):

Since you included the jQuery library, you might try the jQuery solution

```
itemSelector: 'masonryImage'
```

that line `masonryImage` needs a dot so it becomes `.masonryImage`

```
var $container = $('#container');
// initialize
$container.masonry({
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.masonryImage'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/88tYe/